# How to display fetched data in react native

Tags: react-native

I successfully posted data in `MongoDB Atlas`, Now i want to display that data in my simple react native App. Data is showing in my terminal but i am not able to display data in my App.

Here is code for Get data form the db.

```
display(){
  fetch('myUrl', {
  method: 'GET'
})
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
   this.setState({
     title: responseJson,
     description: responseJson
   })
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });
}
```

Here is the code that is not displaying the data in App

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.display()} style={styles.btn}>
  <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}> Display </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<View>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.title}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
    keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: can you also share what come under responseJson

Comment: In responceJson I got all the posted data like title, description etc on my terminal. But when I add flat list for it is giving the error **null is not an object (this.state.title)**

Comment: can you alos share your console where you print this line console.log(responseJson);

Comment: Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5dede264e74a14d7e284",
    "date": "2019-12-09T05:48:50.721Z",
    "description": "Bad",
    "title": "Monday",
  },
]

Comment: I am getting the data but i am not able to display on screen properly that is the issue

Comment: plese proper as screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatlist [data](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data) property expects an array.

But you seem to set an object.

If your api returns an array you can make the following changes to make it work:

```js
state = {
   items:[]
}

display() {
  fetch('myUrl', { method: 'GET'})
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
   this.setState({
        items: responseJson
   })
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });
}
```

As you see I used items in state as array, and updated its value when I got response from api.

And in flatlist:

```js
<View>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.items}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text key={item._id}>{item.title}</Text>}
    keyExtractor={ item => item._id}
    />
</View>
```

[A sample codesandbox](https://snack.expo.io/@suleymansah/a80116)

Comment: i got an error with this code > TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.items')

Comment: @AbdulWahab did you add this code to your component state = { items:[] }

Comment: @AbdulWahab does you api returns an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, this object returning two item > title and description

Comment: @AbdulWahab is it like [{"title":"t1", description:"d1}, {"title":"t2", description:"d2} ] ?

Comment: @AbdulWahab then I see no reason for that error, please check again. And also look at my sample codesandbox. Can you share your full component code in pastebin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203901/discussion-between-abdul-wahab-and-suleymansah).

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like this:

```
this.state = {
  responseData:[]
}
display = () => {
  fetch('myUrl', {
  method: 'GET'
})
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log(responseJson);
   this.setState({
     responseData: responseJson,
   })
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error(error);
 });
}
```

inside your render function:

```
render(){
  const { responseData } = this.state;
  return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.display} style={styles.btn}>
      <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}> Display </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={responseData}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
    </View> 
  );
}
renderItem = ({item}) => {
  const { title, id, description, date } = item;

  <View key={item.id}>
    <Text>{item.id}</Text>
    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    <Text>{item.description}</Text>
    <Text>{item.date}</Text>
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Hope it will help you @Abdul Wahab

Comment: Tysm for your help. BTW It is throwing an err on this ** const { responseData } = this.state;** and the error is > TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.responseData')

Comment: have you define` this.state = {
  responseData:[]
}` or Can you share your code ?

Comment: Please share your code , it will helpful for anyone to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**try with return keywork**
[Working demo api](https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-OfXZZlXFG&preview=true&platform=web&iframeId=cbe524p4p5&supportedPlatforms=ios,android,web&name=Fetch%20Example&description=Example%20usage&waitForData=true)

```
display(){

     return fetch('myUrl', {
      method: 'GET'
    })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       console.log(responseJson);
       this.setState({
         title: responseJson,
         description: responseJson
       })
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
    }
```